# HTTPレスポンスはどうやって返ってくるのか

Tags: http

HTTPリクエストにはヘッダに宛先のアドレスがありますが、HTTPレスポンスには宛先は書いてないようです。
HTTPレスポンスはどうやって返ってくるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPが使用するTCP/IPは双方向通信です。Webサーバーとしてはリクエストを受信した通信に対してそのままレスポンスを返すことができます。
HTTP/3ではTCP/IPを使用しなくなりましたが、QUICという別の双方向通信プロトコルを使用しています。

> HTTPリクエストにはヘッダに宛先のアドレスがありますが

リクエストヘッダにある `Host` はクライアント側が自己申告している接続先ホストであり、実際の接続先と一致しているとは限りません。ごく稀に、`Host`に記載した接続先とは別のWebサーバーに接続させることもあります。

Comment: 「TCP/IP」はTCPとIPを使用した通信という意味だけではなく、TCPとUDPとIPを使用したプロトコル体系全般を意味する場合があります(例えば、TCP/IPの説明するサイトの一項目としてUDPがあるといったように)。後者の意味で捉えてしまうとQUICKはTCP/IPのUDPを使用しているはずなのに別だと言われて混乱するかと思います。TCP/IPという表現はやめた方がいいのではないでしょうか？